# horizontal scrollbar issue with css

Tags: css

I am newbie to CSS. I just started my first website and almost done with the landing page. However, there are two issues I am struck and still not figured what is the root cause. I have created a plukr link http://plnkr.co/edit/aH8LfC?p=preview.

1. Horizontal scroll bar is appearing and there is a gap on the left side even though the width is set to 100%.
2. The third box below the banner is taller than the other two even when they all share the same `CSS` classes.

Code for the three div boxes:

```
    <div class="container info-box clearfix">
        <div class="col3">
          <h3>Investment Planning</h3>
          <p>Money Plant Services is one of the premier Investment advisory Firm known for making taxation & investing simpler and more understandable and profitable for the clients. Currently serving more than 5000 Individual customers with corporate tie ups.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col3">
            <h3>Wealth Management</h3>
            <p>Money Plant Services is one of the premier Investment advisory Firm known for making taxation & investing simpler and more understandable and profitable for the clients. Currently serving more than 5000 Individual customers with corporate tie ups.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col3">
            <h3>Risk Management</h3>
            <p>Money Plant Services is one of the premier Investment advisory Firm known for making taxation & investing simpler and more understandable and profitable for the clients. Currently serving more than 5000 Individual customers with corporate tie ups.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .info-box{
   width:100%;
   margin-top: 20px;
 }

.col3{
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #DDDDDD;
}
```

Could anyone help me understand where I am going wrong. I am not using Bootstrap/Foundation frameworks because I need to get the hang of pure CSS.

Note: The web page has to be loaded in full window to see the issue.

Regards,
Pradeep

Comment: Please put your code in your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This overflow is caused by your left/right paddings, which are **not** included in the width, unless you add this CSS :

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[**Updated Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/qHcRXZx1zL6mN48wXNaf?p=preview)

This means (with a `100px` width) your element size will be `100px` **from left border to right border**. If you set a `15px` padding, you'll have :

- Left padding: 15px
- Right padding: 15px
- Content: (100 - 2 * 15) = 70px
- Total : (70 + 2 * 15) = 100px

If you keep the default value for `box-sizing`, you'll have :

- Left padding: 15px
- Right padding: 15px
- Content: 100px
- Total : (100 + 2 * 15) = 130px

Comment: Hi. The unevenness in the height of the third box is still present. How to make them of the same height. They all have the same style class.

Comment: @Pradeep your unevenness in heights is caused by extra whitespace in your last box.. either get rid of the white space or give them fixed height (in your code, stick the last </p> to the text above, like in the first two boxes..)

Comment: +1. `box-sizing` is the correct solution here, not a negative margin. Bootstrap also uses `border-box` to fix this same issue. For additional reading, there is a further explanation here: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score 1):

The scrollbar is caused by padding on the container and footer. The padding is pushing the content off the canvas. The CSS for the boxes do not have a defined height, so the height is based on the amount of content inside.

I think you need something between the container and columns to offset the padding (usually a negative margin will do it).

Comment: Whats the best way to resolve the issue, I mean for the footer. Also what's the root cause of the second issue

Comment: Put something between the container and columns with a negative margin on the left and right to offset the padding. Bootstrap uses rows. HTML5 boilerplate uses grid. For the columns, you just need to set height or else use code to make them equal height. In your example the closing paragraph tag needs to be moved up. There is some empty space causing extra height.

Comment: Could you please reply with your email id or send a test mail to pradeep.kumar44@gmail.com. I want to chat with you to understand more on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Pradeep Using a negative margin is too much, and not necessary, see my answer.

Comment: @Aibrean Am I not using the Boilerplate code correctly? Where am I going wrong. This is the first time I am writing `html` and `CSS`.

Comment: If you use @zessx's fix you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The additional height on your last box is because you set:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

The `pre-wrap` property is specified as:

> Sequences of whitespace are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at <br>, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

In your HTML, only the last box has a newline in it:

```
<p>Money Plant Services ...
</p>
```

So that newline and whitespace are all preserved due to `white-space: pre-wrap`, which makes that `<p>` element taller to fit the text plus the newline and whitespace at the end.